# Processing error: x cannot be resolved or is not a field (java with the processing app)

Tags: java, processing

So I am using processing in java mode.

There is a function: `ellipse(int,int,int,int)` that draws an ellipse.

I want this program to add a bullet object to the bulletHolder arraylist when the mouse is clicked and then display ellipses for each of these bullet objects based on their x and y property values.

however an error is occurring saying that 'x cannot be resolved or is not a field'

on the line: `ellipse((int) bulletHolder.get(i).x, (int) bulletHolder.get(i).y, 50, 50);`

Here is my full code

```
public ArrayList<Bullet[]>  bulletHolder= new ArrayList<Bullet[]>();
int count = 0;
void setup(){
  size(500,500); 
}


void draw(){
  if(count!=0){
    for(int i =0; i<count; i++){
       ellipse(bulletHolder.get(i).x, bulletHolder.get(i).y, 50, 50); 
    }
  }
}

void mouseClicked(){
  bulletHolder.add(new Bullet(mouseX,mouseY));
  count++;
}

class Bullet {
  int x;
  int y;
  Bullet(int x,int y){
   this.x = x;
   this.y=y; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you converting an int to an int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 bulletHolder.add(new Bullet(mouseX,mouseY)); <--- here JVM trying to convert Bullet instance to array of Bullet instace. It can't be done
```

You are trying to use Bullet instance in to the ArrayList where it requires a Array of Bullet instance. That is why you rare getting that error.

You can either change your ArrayList to accept Bullet instance rather than an array or you can pass bullet array without changing the ArrayList declaration.

Comment: Ah I see, an arraylist requires arrays so it is converting the bullet instances to arrays

Answer (score 2):

bulletHolder is an `ArrayList` that contains arrays of `Bullet`, so to get to `x` member of `Bullet` you have to add an array index :

`bulletHolder.get(i)[index].x`